# can't decrypt the AES256 encrypted text

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, encryption, aes

I have used so many libraries and so many functions but can't decrypt it.

```
NSString *key = @"innoways21897016";
NSString *iv = @"61079821218970166107982121897016";
NSString *encrypted = @"iG5lIZKGevzV3UfhcqOzgA/xwKhAKjB75G1L4Z1s/RU=";
NSData *data = [encrypted dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *dataDecrypted = [data AES256DecryptWithKey:key andIV:iv];
NSLog(@"decrypt data = %@",dataDecrypted);
NSString *receivedDataDecryptString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:dataDecrypted encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"decrypt string = %@",receivedDataDecryptString);
```

`receivedDataDecryptString` always giving me (null) response not a decrypt string.

output will be - "heidi"

Thanks.

Comment: output of `dataDecrypted` is not `null`?

Comment: @Mr.UB output of dataDecrypted is :- <32ae3256 8da8e235 39c1c057 5a9f8809 6b6b5c4b 93f38976 18ea9836 cff565f3 04608f7c 10bc01>
when i convert into string at that time its returning - (null)

Comment: Are you sure that the data you are converting to an NSString is UTF8?  Try `NSASCIIStringEncoding`

Comment: Also, which `NSData+AES` category library are you using?

Comment: @mttrb
yes, i am sure that its UTF8.
i am using NSData+AES256.h and .m library.

- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key andIV:(NSString *)iv;

Comment: This result can mean any number of things: wrong key, wrong encoding, incomplete/overfull ciphertext. You should show the encryption code and give the example values that you've used. Otherwise, it would be plain guessing what might be wrong with this code (or the encryption code). In short, please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @NiravKotecha There are many different implementations of `NSData+AES256`, which one specifically are you using? Either include the encryption code in your example or give a link to the code you are using.

Comment: @mttrb
https://www.dropbox.com/s/z8b04qod5l26dit/NSData%2BAES256.m?dl=0
AES256 Methods - you can see in this link.

Comment: @ArtjomB. you can also refer above link. i have try all method in that library but not working.

Comment: If you have a problem with your code, then you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem. Help us help you without wasting time on guessing. Also, don't provide a link to your code. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code. Links break all the time and if it does, this question will lose all value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some errors and potential errors:

1. You are specifying AES with a 256-bit key (`AES256DecryptWithKey`) but supplying a 128-bit (16-byte) key. Either specify AES with a 128-bit key or provide a 256-bit key.
2. AES has a block size of 16-bytes you are supplying a 32-byte IV, the IV should be 16-Bytes.

Perhaps you have the key and IV reversed.

3. You are supplying the encrypted data in Base64 encoding, the encryption method probably expects the input to be `NSData` or NSString. The length must be a multiple of the block size, 16-bytes for AES, supplying encrypted data of the wrong length is one of the few ways you will get an error from `CCCrypt` which the decryption method is most likely using.
4. You have not provided the expected decrypted result, this makes testing a solution difficult.
5. The encrypted data is 32 bytes (after decoding the Base64). "heidi" is less than a block size so will pad to 16-bytes. That leaves a mystery 16-bytes.

Comment: Added item 5 to the answer.

Comment: 16 byte IV + 16 byte padded cipher block = 32 bytes of output.

Comment: @zaph but android side working with this key and IV. they are using "PaddedBufferedBlockCipher" Library. some kind of bouncy castle jar file